# Three.js file not included in my HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am learning HTML5, and i use Three.js 3D engine. following [this example](http://www.aerotwist.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-three-js/), the tutorial assume i included `three.js` file into my HTML file. However, i found two files with that name, so i included both but nothing appear to work.

In my html file:

```
<script src="three.js/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="three.js/src/Three.js"></script>
```

Three.js package is in the same directory as my html file and it's in a folder called three.js.

Am i including the wrong file(s)?

**EDIT**

When i debug in Mozilla FireFox, i got this message:

```
[13:41:04.275] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @
```

The line causing the error is this:

```
// get the DOM element to attach to
// - assume we've got jQuery to hand
var $container = $('#container');
```

Thanx for help.

Comment: Have you ever tried Firebug for Firefox (I think something similar, Firebug lite, is available for chrome). Firebug lets you step through javascript code and gives you a lot more useful information than just the browser. Also, if you are using firefox you can use the developer console to get some error messages, which will help you fix your issue.

Comment: @WayneUroda Modern versions of browsers Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE has built in tools. Firebug lite is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since r50 it should be:

```
<script src="three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to be a jQuery issue now. Nothing to do with three.js.

Answer (score 1):

If the js file is in the same directory you should just do

```
<script src="three.js"></script>
```

The path to the file inside the `src` attribute is relative to the current file.

Comment: "Three.js **package** is in the same directory as my html file and it's in a folder called three.js."

Comment: I edited my post, i think it's related to a jQuery library which is missing, but i can not find any reference for jQuery in the Three.je folder.